# App download size while using Play Asset delivery

Tags: android, google-play, android-app-bundle

I want to start using Android App Bundle instad of APK+OBB.
App Bundle documentation says, that app download size is restricted to 150mB.
But recently Play Asset Delivery has been introduced, and it must have 1 GB limit to install-time asset packs:

https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/asset-delivery

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/11/modern-app-and-game-distribution-on.html

In the second article, it is said, that Play Asset Delivery is developed to break 150mB limit.

But I have built an app with Google Asset Delivery (Unity project, ~300 MB size), and can't create an alpha release with this app (150 mB limit).

Has anyone encountered this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for trying out the new feature. I can confirm that it should be possible to upload large bundles if they use Play Asset Delivery.

Regarding your issue:
The screenshot you have provided actually only shows a warning. It is warning you that for larger apps the Play Store app will show a warning for users if they attempt to download it over cellular data. This is shown for all large apps, also for apps with OBBs to make sure that the user does not spend too much data.

It should still be possible to upload the bundle. Could you check if you can upload the bundle regardless of this warning?

Answer (score 1):

I have just realized that you have not filled out the "Content Rating" and "App Content" section for your app (the ticks are grey on the right side of your screenshot).

All sections with ticks must be completed before an app can be rolled out (signalized by a green tick).